# Can't link assets (fonts) in react native >= 0.60

Tags: react-native

```
react-native: 0.60.4,
react: 16.8.6,
npm: 6.10.1
XCode: 10.2.1
AndroidStudio: 3.4.1
```

I created a project using

`npx react-native init awesomeApp --template typescript`

I have put my assets in the

```
assets/fonts/<Bunch of .ttf files>
```

My Directory Structure

```
awesomeApp
|
+--android
+--ios
+--assets
|  |
|  +---fonts
|      |
|      +-- ProximaNova-Bold.ttf
+--react-native-config.js
```

then I ran
`react-native link`

Nothing happends, XCode not showing any added Resource neither the android, and when I'm running `react-native run-ios` showing error that the font is not found.

My `react-native-config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    project: {
        ios: {},
        android: {},
    },
    assets: ['./assets/fonts']
};
```

I have also tried 
`yarn react-native link` and `npx react-native link`

Comment: It's a nice example of using react-native config file.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Well,
finally, I linked my fonts,

I just renamed my file `react-native-config.js` to `react-native.config.js` and it worked.

I don't know if this is the right way, I just tried and it worked, for me at least.

Here is the complete walkthrough for [linking custom fonts](https://garbagevalue.com/blog/use-custom-fonts-in-react-native).

Comment: Thanks, I spent way too long trying things out before I realized I also had this mistake...

Comment: Where  ```react-native.config.js``` is located? i need its address in root project

Comment: It is in the root. @roz333

Answer (score 13):

For React-native > 0.69, `npx react-native link` is no longer working

Use `npx react-native-asset` instead

Comment: Is there a solution to this without using third party library?

Answer (score 8):

my react-native.config.js

```
module.exports = {
project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {},
},
assets: ['./assets/fonts/'],
};
```

and logs:

```
info Linking assets to ios project                                                                                      
info Linking assets to android project                                                                                  
success Assets have been successfully linked to your project
```

but My mistake was:

Wrong way:

```
fontFamily: BYekan
```

Right way:

```
fontFamily: 'BYekan'
```

just put font name in ''

Comment: Not the question I was asking.

Answer (score 4):

Create a file in your react native project called `react-native.config.js`:

In it, paste

```
module.exports = {
    project: {
      ios: {},
      android: {},
    },
    assets: ['./src/assets/fonts/'],
};
```

`assets: ['./src/assets/fonts/'],` should be the path to wherever you stored your custom fonts in your project folder.
When you run the link command, it should work then.

Answer (score 3):

Just to complement keyserfaty's answer, here is my react-native.config.js working using react-native link:

```
module.exports = {
  dependencies: {
    "react-native-gesture-handler": { platforms: { android: null, ios: null } }
  },
  assets: ['./src/assets/fonts']
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Using RN 0.60.8 with a `react-native-config.js` file should allow you to link your fonts using `react-native link`.

My logs:

```
react-native link       
info Linking assets to ios project
info Linking assets to android project
success Assets have been successfully linked to your project
```

Since you installed React Native using `npx` I'm guessing you maybe don't have `react-native` installed globally? Is running `react-native link` giving you any errors?

Comment: No, I'm getting the same log as yours, but nothing actually getting linked.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above solutions work for me. The issue with what I was having is my Xcode project already had `Resources` group with a backed folder in it. The way `react-native link` is working as my understanding is it's creating a group without a folder and add it to your project and link to all your fonts from there. This approach doesn't work when you already have a `Resources` folder. The solution I could come up with was just renaming the `Resources` folder to something else and run `react-native link` again.

If you don't have such a setup, create `react-native.config.js` file and running `react-native link` works fine.

`react-native.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    project: {
        ios: {},
        android: {},
    },
    assets: ['./src/assets/fonts/']
};
```

Answer (score 1):

change  assets: ['./src/assets/fonts/'] to assets: ['/src/assets/fonts/']

or use

assets: ['./src/assets/fonts/'] but nameProject/assets

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

some times you have writed react-native.config.js correctlly

in such cases ; if you do this tasks

it helps you

1- delete react-native.config.js file

2- create this file with same code again

3- write react-native link in console

then you can see resources folder in Xcode

and you can see your fonts in info.plist and copy bundle resources

Answer (score -5):

The "adding the font" should be done in your package.json. Add:

```
"rnpm": {
 "assets": ["./assets/fonts/"]
}
```

Then run

```
react-native link
```

[Source](https://blog.bam.tech/developper-news/add-a-custom-font-to-your-react-native-app)

**EDIT: The above only works for react-native below 0.60.0**

Comment: No, please check the 0.60.x docs, rnpm is deprecated now. You should use react-native-config.js now.

Comment: And the source you've given is more than 2 years old.

Comment: Sorry, about that I wasn't aware of rnpm no longer work in 0.60. I checked the same issue in Github and the only different I can see is that you're missing the "/" at the end of your directory which may confuse how the system would read it. As weird as it may sound, have you try adding that and run react-native link?

Comment: I am facing a issue I have deleted fonts from iOS and android. And installing again using npx react-native link. But it is not linking fonts again. Anybody faces the same problem?