# Custom fonts not working on React-Native 0.62

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to use a custom font on my app but it doesn't work. I have followed numerous steps from other similar questions but nothing works.

I'm not getting any error.

The path to the assets folder:
[Assets source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loEph.png)

This is what I tried:

1. - Creating react-native.config.js file on root project with the following code:

```
module.exports = {
    project: {
      ios: {},
      android: {},
    },
    assets: ['./src/assets/fonts']
  };
```

2. - Running react-native link:
     This didnt give me any errors:

```
info Linking assets to ios project
info Linking assets to android project
success Assets have been successfully linked to your project
```

3. - Naming the font exactly as its named in styles WITHOUT using any fontWeight:

```
<Text style={[styles.texto_Titulo, {fontFamily: "LatoBlack"}]}>
      ENTRADA
</Text>
```

4. - Recompiling with npx react-native run-android after react-native link

Why is this not working?

Comment: After linking are you see any changes in Android/app/main folders?

Comment: @OliverD Not in android/app/main but in android/src/ I got an assets/fonts folder with fonts

Comment: Yup, I'm trying this way and it works for me! Check if the font file name as you type in ur code "fontFamily" or not, and the font is valid, the last thing uninstall the app and rebuild it

Comment: @OliverD I dont think I completly understood you, can you please explain?

Comment: you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57130259/cant-link-assets-fonts-in-react-native-0-60) also

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay so this happens to be a current bug for React Native 0.62. The workaround for this problem is copying the assets/fonts folder to /android/app/src/main/ path. This fixed the problem.

Comment: Would you be able to link the GitHub issue?

Comment: @AidanH what do you mean? I dont know if theres any issue open on the react-native github about this, I just know that there're plenty more of people with the exact same problem

Comment: @AdriánOrtellsCasado I'm having the same problem in my new `React Native 0.62.2` and I copied the `fonts` folder into `/android/app/src/main` folder but the icons are still not showing up. I followed the this https://www.reactnative.guide/12-svg-icons-using-react-native-vector-icons/12.1-creating-custom-iconset.html to add my custom icons. The only thing I did NOT do is to link. Do I need to link `react-native-vector-icons`? They work without linking which is why I did not link.

Comment: @Sam this problem is just for the fonts, I dont know if it also happens with icons, I had no problem using the ones from fontawesome

Comment: This is also the case for `0.63.3`

Comment: same for me 0.63.3

Comment: I have the same issue, however in my case the react-native has linked fonts successfully and it copied the files to the **app\android\app\src\main\assets\fonts** correctly with corresponding references created in list and other files I don't remember names , I also have used the proper PostScript names in the code and still the issue persists. I am using **react-native-cli: 2.0.1** and **react-native: 0.63.4**, any help on this would be a great help.

Answer (score 9):

My solution was to remove fontWeight from my text styles. Seems font family does not work if fontWeight is provided

Comment: Yeah helped me :)
this should be more visible, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25852#issuecomment-826526064

still i have face same issue on 0.64.0

#### **Solution**

please copy paste your font file to

`android/app/src/main/assets/fonts`

*if you have not find the folder of asset inside main folder. please create it assets/fonts folder*

Then do
`react-native link`

**its working now** without adding any config

Answer (score 1):

Guys if you are following all other solution and still no update then try following steps

1. add react-native-config.js file
2. then add fonts in assets/fonts/your font
3. rename it with lowercase like OpenSans_Regular to opensans_regular
4. react-native link in terminal in your project folder
5. after all build your project again using react-native run-android
6. ```
       fontFamily: Platform.OS === "ios" ? 'opensans_regular' : 'cassandrapersonaluseregular_3bjg',
   ```

I was also getting the same issue the font was not reflecting changes then I build my project again that was my mistake because we adding fonts in our android folder so we need to compile that again.
I hope someone may save their time

Comment: just to correct you the file name should be react-native.config.js not react-native-config.js as mentioned  in first point.

Answer (score 0):

NO: 1 === i give a perfact solution to add custom fonts in react native app
make a file on root name assets, inside assets folder make fonts folder and inside fonts folder paste your fonts files.
NO: 2 === make a file on root of project file name is `react-native.config.js` in side file paste below code

```
  **
  module.exports = {
  project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {}, // grouped into "project"
  },
  assets: ['./assets/fonts'], 
  };
```

**

now run a command to connect your fonts
command is === `npx react-native-asset`