# Showing SVG image with 'react-native-svg' library, however encounter 'Unrecognized font family' error in iOS (Android works fine.)

Tags: react-native, svg, react-native-ios, react-native-svg

My react-native version is "0.62.2".

In order to show remote SVG images, I use [react-native-svg](https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg) library in my React Native project.

I use it like:

```
import {SvgUri} from 'react-native-svg';

const MyScreen = ({route, navigation}) => {
  ...
  ...
  return (<View>
        <SvgUri width="100%" height="100%" uri={imageSource} />
        </View>)
}

export default MyScreen;
```

In Android emulator, it works fine!

In **iOS**, it works in a sense, but the way how it works is: when navigate to `MyScreen`, I always encounter the following error at runtime in the 1st place:

[image]

Then, I have to press on keyboard ctrl+S to save code again (though nothing needs to save) which triggers the simulator to refresh, then `MyScreen` is shown successfully with the SVG image.

Why I get the "Unrecognized font family 'Univers-Condensed'" error at runtime in iOS? How to get rid of it?

(In my code, I have no code using that font, so my guess is the library introduced that font.)

Comment: Specify a different font.

Comment: How to specify a different font? I mean that font in the error is not something I have declared or in use. That's why I don't understand why that error, most likely from the library I am using.

Comment: font="<whatever font you want>" or font-family="<whatever font familty you want>"

Comment: Do I need to download the font file firstly from somewhere?

Comment: Depends on whether it's already present on the device or not.

Comment: What if it is not present on the device? Do you have a step by step guide reference to solve that?

Comment: then you'll need to obtain it from somewhere e.g. you could specify it as a data url

Comment: You need to download the font and add to the ios project and info.plist file.

Comment: Follow this tutorial: https://medium.com/@mehrankhandev/ultimate-guide-to-use-custom-fonts-in-react-native-77fcdf859cf4 and add the font to your iOS project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this add `Universe-Condensed.ttf` in info.plist

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>Universe-Condensed.ttf</string>
    </array>
```

Answer (score 2):

`This happens when your app is trying to access the given font family and that specific font is not linked with your project` and this error can happen only be on a single platform (Android, IOS) because these fonts linked separately on both platforms.

**Solution:**

1. Remove usage of `Univers-Condensed` font family in your JS code because JS code is the trigger point of this error.

**Note:**  This solution will not work if this error is produced by some library that you are using in your project and that is using that `Univers-Condensed` font family.

2. Another solution is, You have to add and link this font family in your project.

- [Download the font .ttf file](https://www.dafontfree.net/freefonts-univers-condensed-f146660.htm)

- Make a folder named assets and inside the assets, folder make the fonts
  folder on the root of the project and put your downloaded font file in it.
- add this to your `react-native.config.js file`

  ```
   module.exports = {
   assets: ['./assets/fonts/']
    };
  ```
- run `react-native link`

this process will automatically link fonts with your IOS and android project too.

Comment: I don't have `react-native-config.js` file by default in my project. Should I manually create that? Should it be put under root of my react-native project?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57130259/cant-link-assets-fonts-in-react-native-0-60 This says I should create `react-native.config.js` instead of `react-native-config.js`. I tried that & the steps in your answer, I still get the same error at runtime.

Comment: And my react-native version is 0.62.2, do I still need to manually link the font with the command `react-native link`?

Comment: Sorry, yes it is react-native.config.js you could rename it also if you don't have a file you can create it, and lastly font will not link automatically even your version is greater then `0.60` so for linking fonts or other assets you have to run the `react-native link`